# how can i remove default tag in ckeditor

Tags: html, textarea

I am using ng-ckeditor with angularjs. When  I enter text init it is by default taking  tag. how could I remove it.And also it is showing the styles am selecting at the bottom . I want to get rid of this too. 
 Can anyone can help me to get out of this problem.
 Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's a bit unclear right now what you mean exactly. Can you illustrate the problem with some code and a jsfiddle? It will be easier to help you out that way.

Comment: when i type a text in the editor it is by default adding <div> tag. I want to remove it. Actually it is default setting in ng-ckeditor.